# Can't open file error link1104 after adding libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio to compile a c++ script that uses libcurl
[tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_mXVZ6VJs4)

1. Downloaded MFC packages and c++ for desktop development and .net then built curl files as shown in the video
2. in advanced / choose MFC static libs
3. Then added the include folder to the c++ / general/ additional directories
4. The lib folder to linker / input / additional dependences

everything was going according to plan until I tried to build the solution, I got the error `LINK1104` cannot find the lib.obj file in the path provided

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "curl/curl.h"

static size_t my_write(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* param)
{
 std::string& text = *static_cast<std::string*>(param);
 size_t totalsize = size * nmemb;
 text.append(static_cast<char*>(buffer), totalsize);
 return totalsize;
}

int main()
{
 std::string result;
 CURL* curl;
 CURLcode res;
 curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
 curl = curl_easy_init();
 if (curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tcno.co/hello.txt");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_write);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &result);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  if (CURLE_OK != res) {
   std::cerr << "CURL error: " << res << '\n';
  }
 }
 curl_global_cleanup();
 std::cout << result << "\n\n";
}
```

I tested the debug and release for both (x86 ,x64 ) but I get the same error for all of them

Comment: Can not open a static or import library file (.lib extension) in Visual Studio usually means 1 or more of the following: 1. You named it differently or its not in any of the folders you told msvc to look, 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit, 3. The file is corrupt.

Comment: The path i added has a file with .lib extension as stated in the video

Comment: You need add the path of the directory which contains .lib file to `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` and lib file name without directory to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`. From your description it seems you missed the first one.